# using sequilize reference with include model for GraphQL

Tags: node.js, graphql

Good afternoon,

Im using sequilize with graphQL, I have three models

```
const Company= db.define('Company',{
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    icon: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
});
Empresa.hasMany(Producto, {as: 'products', foreignKey: 'CompanyId'});

const Product = db.define('Product',{
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    price: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    icon: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
});
Product.belongsTo(Company, {as: 'company', foreignKey: 'CompanyId'});
Producto.hasMany(Off, {as: 'offs', foreignKey: 'ProductID'});

const Off= db.define('Off',{
    day: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    off: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    description: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
});
Off.belongsTo(Product, {as: 'product', foreignKey: 'ProductID'});


getCompany: async () => {
            const companies = await Company.findAll({model:Producto, as: 'productos'}]});
            return companies ;
        },
```

its working good, I can get the name of the company and their productos

```
getProducto: async () => {
            const products = await Producto.findAll({include: [{model:Company, as: 'company'},

{model:Off, as: 'off'}]});
            return products;
        },
```

its working good as well, I can get products and their off, nevertheless when I want

```
query GetCompanies {
  getCompanies {
    name
    products {
      name
      off{
        off
        description
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can get the products, but I see a null the off, its like I can go two levels down or up, somebody know, thanks

```
graphQL return
{
  "data": {
    "GetCompanies": [
      {
        "name": "Exito",
        "products": [
          {
            "name": "pescado robalo",
            "off": null
          },
          {
            "name": "carne milanesa",
            "off": null
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Macro",
        "products": [
          {
            "name": "ponymalta",
            "off": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I think its something on the find(include)

Answer (score 0):

I did it with

```
Company.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Product, 
        as: 'products', 
        include:[{ model:Off, as: 'offs' }]
    }]
});
```